# Why is the non-const member function being called, instead of the const one?

Tags: c++, constants, operator-overloading, overload-resolution, function-qualifier

I tried to wrap something similar to Qt's shared data pointers for my purposes, and upon testing I found out that when the const function should be called, its non-const version was chosen instead.

I'm compiling with C++0x options, and here is a minimal code:

```
struct Data {
    int x() const {
        return 1;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct container
{
    container() {
        ptr = new T();
    }


    T & operator*() {
        puts("non const data ptr");
        return *ptr;
    }

    T * operator->() {
        puts("non const data ptr");
        return ptr;
    }

    const T & operator*() const {
        puts("const data ptr");
        return *ptr;
    }

    const T * operator->() const {
        puts("const data ptr");
        return ptr;
    }

    T* ptr;
};

typedef container<Data> testType;

void testing() {
    testType test;
    test->x();
}
```

As you can see, Data.x is a const function, so the operator -> called should be the const one. And when I comment out the non-const one, it compiles without errors, so it's possible. Yet my terminal prints:

> "non const data ptr"

Is it a GCC bug (I have 4.5.2), or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have two overloads that differ only in their `const`-ness, then the compiler resolves the call based on whether `*this` is `const` or not.  In your example code, `test` is not `const`, so the non-`const` overload is called.

If you did this:

```
testType test;
const testType &test2 = test;
test2->x();
```

you should see that the other overload gets called, because `test2` is `const`.

Comment: so the compiler will prefer to call the non-const overload if the object is not declared const, even if it could call the const overload?

Comment: @coyotte508: Precisely.  The non-`const` overload is considered a better match.

Comment: Since C++20 you could also do this: `testType test; std::as_const(test).x();`

Comment: @coyotte508 just out of curiosity, if the compiler preferred the const overload even if the object is not declared const, then what's the point of non-const overloading?

Comment: @starriet When I wrote the question I had the assumption that the compiler would choose the function based on the return type, eg if I needed a non-const pointer as a return type it would use the non-const function, otherwise the const function.

Answer (score 15):

`test` is a non-const object, so the compiler finds the best match: The non-const version. You can apply constness with `static_cast` though: `static_cast<const testType&>(test)->x();`

EDIT: As an aside, as you suspected 99.9% of the time you think you've found a compiler bug you should revisit your code as there's probably some weird quirk and the compiler is in fact following the standard.

Comment: +1 for the "you probably haven't found a bug in the compiler" comment

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether `Data::x` is a constant function or not. The operator being called belongs to `container<Data>` class and not `Data` class, and its instance is not constant, so non-constant operator is called. If there was only constant operator available or the instance of the class was constant itself, then constant operator would have been called.

Answer (score 1):

But `testType` is not a const object.

Thus it will call the non const version of its members.
If the methods have exactly the same parameters it has to make a choice on which version to call (so it uses the this parameter (the hidden one)). In this case this is not const so you get the non-const method.

```
testType const test2;
test2->x();  // This will call the const version
```

This does not affect the call to x() as you can call a const method on a non const object.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last sentence? What does it mean _"does not affect the call to x()"_ and _"on a non-const object"_? I thought the `test2` in your code is a const object. By the way, thanks for a clear explanation with the hidden 'this' parameter.