# Problems with an iterator and an const_iterator in the same class

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm writing a class "translator" and I need two iterators, one constant and other more normal.
This is the interesting zone of code:

```
...

iterator begin() {
  iterator i;
  i.puntero=palabras.begin();
  return i;
}
iterator end(){
  iterator i;
  i.puntero=palabras.end();
  return i;
}
...
const_iterator begin() const  {
  const_iterator i;
  i.puntero=palabras.begin();
  return i;
}
const_iterator end() const {
  const_iterator i;
  i.puntero=palabras.end();
  return i;
}
...
```

There are more code but I think that isn't interesting.

Well, I need use the iterators in a for loops and is in this moment when the code fail:

```
  #Work fine
  for(Traductor::iterator it=traductor.begin(); it!=traductor.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->first << endl;

  #Don't work
  for (Traductor::const_iterator it=traductor.begin(); it!=traductor.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->first << endl;
```

The error is:

```
 error: conversion from ‘Traductor::iterator’ to non-scalar type ‘Traductor::const_iterator’ requested    for (Traductor::const_iterator it=traductor.begin(); it!=traductor.end(); ++it)
```

And i don't know how make to the program uses the const_iterator in the second loop and don't try to use the normal.

Any idea? Thanks you so much.

**Solution adopted:**

Finally, If I use a const `traductor` isn't necessary to changing the name to `end` and `begin` methods but if `traductor` isn't not  constant i need use `cend` and `cbegin` methods.

Example:

```
  #When is constant:
  const Traductor tradConst = traductor;
```

for (Traductor::const_iterator it=tradConst.begin(); it!=tradConst.end(); ++it)

```
  #When isn't, use diferent methods to differentiate:
  //for (Traductor::const_iterator it=traductor.cbegin(); it!=traductor.cend(); ++it)

...
```

So, I have:

```
const_iterator begin() const {...}
const_iterator end() const {...}
iterator begin() {...}
iterator end(){...}
```

Useful when I use constant and non-constant objects, and when I want use const and non-const iterator in a non-const object I will change the name of the methods:

```
const_iterator cbegin() const {...}
const_iterator cend() const {...}
iterator begin() {...}
iterator end(){...}
```

Thanks you so much guys!

Comment: Make `iterator` implicitely convertable into `const_iterator` (by either implicit constructor on conversion operator)

Comment: In the "Don't work" case, is `traductor` declared as `const`? (cf. [Calling a const function rather than its non-const version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7287065/865719))

Comment: This is precisely why `cbegin()` and `cend()` were added to standard containers. Worth researching that...

Comment: When we add const to the member function ... Does not it get called only for const object ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Finally, i have adopted this solution in a part, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the thing you're initialising has very little (read: no) bearing on how the function call in the initialiser will be resolved.

That means, **when `traductor` is non-`const`, your non-`const` `begin()` and `end()` will *always* be used!**

You can fix this by allowing `iterator` to implicitly convert to `const_iterator`. There is also the option of adding `cbegin()` and `cend()` functions that explicitly, always, return `const_iterator`. [This is "safer" in a number of cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001519/560648).

The standard library containers do both.

Comment: Totally true, if I use a const `traductor` isn't necessary to changing the name to `end` and `begin` methods but if `traductor` isn't not  constant i need use `cend` and `cbegin` methods.

Answer (score 3):

Unless `traductor` is `const`, `traductor.begin()` returns an `iterator`.

You have to provide a constructor of `const_iterator` which takes an `iterator` (or add an `operator const_iterator` in iterator).

Comment: Totally true, if I use a const `traductor` isn't necessary to changing the name to `end` and `begin` methods but if `traductor` isn't not  constant i need use `cend` and `cbegin` methods.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that object `traductor` is not a constant object. so as result non constant overloaded functions `begin` and `end` are called in this loop

```
for (Traductor::const_iterator it=traductor.begin(); it!=traductor.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->first << endl;
```

You could write

```
for (Traductor::const_iterator it= const cast<const Traductor &>( traductor ).begin(); it!=const cast<const Traductor &>( traductor ).end(); ++it)
    cout << it->first << endl;
```

Another approach is to define functions `cbegin` and `cend` specially for selecting the `const_iterator`.

Comment: Would you actually write this code though? Pretty verbose, isn't it?