# Range expression of range-based for loops to use const function overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, foreach

**Update, thanks to AlexD's answer**: This question boils down to the language rules for selecting member function overloads, which is discussed in the following question: [Calling a const function rather than its non-const version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287065/calling-a-const-function-rather-than-its-non-const-version/7287093#7287093)

---

When the range expression of a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is a call to a member function with `const` and non-`const` overloads, it seems that the non-`const` overload is selected. As a result, the following program does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class foo {
    public:
        const std::vector<int>& get_numbers() const { return numbers; }
    protected:
        std::vector<int>& get_numbers() { return numbers; }
    private:
        std::vector<int> numbers;
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    for (int x : f.get_numbers()) std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Diagnostic message from gcc 5.3:

> `error: ‘std::vector<int>& foo::get_numbers()’ is protected`

But a `const` version of `get_numbers()` is available and could be used. We can force it to be used by using a `const` reference to the `foo` instance, like this:

```
int main() {
    foo f;
    const foo& g = f;
    for (int x : g.get_numbers()) std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a better/easier way to tell the compiler that it can and should use the `const` member function overload, without explicitly making a `const` reference to the object?

There are some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104/c11-range-based-loop-get-item-by-value-or-reference-to-const) about making the range-based for loop use `const` iterators, but I haven't found any questions about making the loop's range expression `const` for the purposes of selecting function overloads.

Comment: I believe this happens because of `f` declared as `foo f;` and not `const foo f;` That's why the non-const overloaded function is selected over const. My question is why do you need the `getNumbers()` both public and private?

Comment: Avoid any private/protected getter/setter (or use a different name)

Comment: @DimChtz Yes, that's the problem. The overload selected is the function signature, not the return type.

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes... this is a contrived example strictly for the purposes of illustrating the problem. This question has nothing to do with proper use of getters, but thanks for your input.

Comment: isn't setting a getter as private kind of defeating the purpose of a getter...?

Comment: I've changed the example to make the non-`const` getter `protected` instead of `private` (this is the situation in my real code that prompted this question, but I changed it here to shorten the example by one line.)

Answer (score 3):

> But a `const` version of `get_numbers()` is available and could be used.

The best function is selected before accessibility is considered. The standard states (emphasis mine):

> If a best viable function exists and is unique, overload resolution succeeds and produces it as the result.
>   Otherwise overload resolution fails and the invocation is ill-formed. ***When overload resolution succeeds, and
>   the best viable function is not accessible*** (Clause 11) in the context in which it is used, the program is
>   ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks, this is good information as far as understanding why the non-`const` overload is selected. But it doesn't quite answer the question of whether there's a more convenient way to select the `const` overload without explicitly making a `const` reference to the instance.

Comment: @TypeIA Some others suggest the same as you did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7287093

Comment: Thanks, that's a great link and I've added it to the top of my question. That linked question really gets at the heart of this issue, which is unrelated to range-based for loops.

Answer (score 0):

A simple template function `as_const` can make the cast not so ugly. I believe this is being added or was recently added to the standard library.

```
template <typename T> T const & as_const (T const & t) { return t; }

void f ()
{
    for (auto && x: as_const (y)) {}
}
```

Comment: C++17, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const. It would be safer to add `template <class T> void as_const(const T&&) = delete;` to prevent dangling references to temporaries.

Comment: nice, I wasn't aware you could delete arbitrary function declarations

Comment: `_T` is reserved. Use something else.

Comment: @T.C. is that better?